# ARM LPC2378 I2C interfacing with HMC5883L

Tags: arm, embedded, keil, lpc

I'm trying to interface LPC2378 I2C0 with HMC5883L. I have written the following code:

```
main () {

    lcd_init();
    lcd_clear();

    PINSEL1 |= 0x01400000;
    I20CONCLR =0x6c; //Clear all flags
    I20CONSET=0X40;  //Enable the interface. 
    I20SCLH=I20SCLL=60; //100 KHz

    VICIntEnable |= 0x0000200; 
    VICVectPriority9 = 1;
    VICVectAddr9 = (unsigned long)ISR_I2C;

    I20CONSET=0X60; //to send Start bit
    while(1)
    {
        // Idle state. Waiting for interrupts.    
    }

}

__irq void ISR_I2C(void) {
    int status;
    status=I20STAT;
    if(status==0X08) 
    {
        I20DAT=0x3C; // Slave address + R/W bit
        lcd_print("Hello"); 
        I20CONCLR=0x28; //start, interrupt clear
    }
    if(status==0X18) 
    {
        I20DAT=0x02;    //Slave ACK, Send data byte
        lcd_print("ACK");
        I20CONCLR=0x08; // interrupt clear
    }
    if(status==0X20) 
    {
        lcd_print("NACK");
        I20CONCLR=0x08; // interrupt clear
    }

    VICVectAddr = 0;

}
```

When I run in simulation (in Keil), I am getting the NACK condition (which is expected as there is no slave to acknowledge), however when I connect to HMC5883L I am neither reaching the ACK or NACK state after transmitting the SLA+W byte. What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Do you know if the problem here is with your i2C driver or with the data you're sending over i2C? If you can isolate that it'll help with solving your problem.

Comment: Also, if you're receiving neither ACK nor NACK, have it print out the value of the I20STAT register and look it up in the datasheet to see what that value means. Running through this step-by-step in a debugger will help you monitor all those registers.

Comment: Sorry but other than that advice, I don't have enough experience with the LPC2378 to help